# $f^\ast (a \smile b) = f^\ast(a) \smile f^\ast(b)$ using simplicial chains to define cochains

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a continuous map between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, $f_\ast$ be the induced homomorphism of singular chains $C_k^s(X;G)$, $C_k^s(Y;G)$ and $f^\ast$ be the induced homomorphism of cochains $C^k(X;G) = \mathrm{Hom}(C_k^s(X;G),G)$ and $C^k(Y;G)$. Then for any $a \in C^p(Y;G)$, $b \in C^q(Y;G)$ and for any singular simplex $x \colon \Delta^{p+q} \to X$ we have
$$
    f^\ast( a \smile b)[x] = (a \smile b)[f_\ast x] = (a \smile b)[ f \circ x] = \\
    = a[ f \circ x \circ i_{0,\ldots,p}] b[f \circ x \circ i_{p,\ldots,p+q}] = f^\ast(a)[x \circ i_{0,\ldots,p}] f^\ast(b)[x \circ i_{p,\ldots, p+q}] = \\
  = \left(f^\ast(a) \smile f^\ast (b) \right) [x]
$$
and hence $f^\ast (a \smile b) = f^\ast(a) \smile f^\ast(b)$.

Now  let $C_\ast(X;G)$, $C_\ast(Y;G)$ be simplicial chain complexes and $C^k(X;G) = \mathrm{Hom}(C_k(X;G),G)$, $C^k(Y;G)$ be corresponding cochain groups and let $g_\ast$ be an arbitrary chain homomorphism from $C_\ast(X;G)$ to $C_\ast(Y;G)$ that induces cochain homomorphism $g^\ast$. I want to show that for any $a,b \in C^k(Y;G)$ and for any $x \in C_k(X;G)$ we have $g^\ast( a \smile b )[x] = \left( g^\ast(a) \smile g^\ast(b) \right) [x]$. I write as for singular case
$$
   g^\ast ( a \smile b)[x] = (a \smile b) [ g_\ast x] = a[  \;_p(g_\ast x)]b[ (g_\ast x)_{q}],
$$
where $_p( g_\ast x )$ is a linear operation that takes the front $p$-face of each simplex, and $(g_\ast x)_q$ is a linear operation that takes the rear $q$ face of each simplex. If equalities $_p (g_\ast x) = g_\ast (_px)$ and $(g_\ast x)_q = g_\ast (x_q)$ hold then all is proven, but why is it true?